# how to sort array list in ascendin or descending order values in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting, arraylist

My array-list value is like below

```
[
{
    Distance=Distance: 16.6km,
    branch_desc=name 1,
},
{
    Distance=Distance: 5.4km,
    branch_desc=name 2,
},
{
    Distance=Distance: 13.4km,
    branch_desc=name 3,
}
]
```

How to sort the array-list to ascending and descending order compare with distance.I don't know how to sort the array list.Can any one know please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: had you tried Collection.sort()?

Comment: *Collections : don't forget the `s`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle no, i dont know how to do that.

Comment: @PankajKumar above is an array-list not a j son array.

Comment: @Yugesh then please provide more information on the type of the elements. Can you give the class definition?

Comment: @Yugesh then there are too many answers avaible on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Comment: It is very simple
For Ascending : Collections.sort(mArrayList, new OutcomeAscComparator());
public class OutcomeAscComparator implements Comparator<Select>
 {
     public int compare(Select left, Select right) {
         return left.getOutcome().compareTo(right.getOutcome());
     }
 }
For Descending: public class OutcomeDescComparator implements Comparator<Select>
 {
     public int compare(Select left, Select right) {
         return right.getOutcome().compareTo(left.getOutcome());
     }
 }

Answer (score 12):

See [`Collections#sort(List<T> list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29). It helps you to sort any list of `T` which implements [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

If your class does not implement Comparable, you can provide a Comparator and call [`static void <T> sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Example with a small class:

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item>{

  private Integer number;
  private Double distance;

  //Getters & Setters
  ...

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Item o) {
    return this.distance > o.distance? -1 : 1;
  }
}
```

As it implements Comparable, you can sort a list like this :

```
List<Item> myItemList = ... ;
Collections.sort(myItemList);
//Now, myItemList is sorted
```

**OR** you can provide a Comparator to sort items on any criteria :

```
List<Item> list = ...;
//Here, I provide a Comparator to sort Items by number.
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Item>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
    return o2.getNumber() - o1.getNumber();
  }
});
```

Comment: how to sort hash map array list with the comparator.

Answer (score 3):

Try This Code

```
List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(10, 5, 4), 
        Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), Arrays.asList(5, 6, 7));
    for (List<Integer> l : list) {
    Collections.sort(l);
    }

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {
    public int compare(List<Integer> o1, List<Integer> o2) {
        return o1.get(0).compareTo(o2.get(0));
    }
});
System.out.println(list);
```

**String Sort**

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a dedicated `Comparator` class extension.
You can whether create one single class and use a boolean to specify if this should be ascending or descending order, or create one class for each order.

The difference will reside in your implementation(s) of [compare(T, T)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29), because this is where you will actually compare objects with criteria you choose, which is in your case the value of the field `Distance`.
Then you call [Collections.sort(ArrayList, Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort the `ArrayList`.

**Using one single class**

```
MyComparator comp = ... // You can even pass the boolean at instanciation
comp.setAscending(true); // 'false' for descending

Collections.sort(list, comp); // Sort is performed - order depends on boolean
```

**Using 2 casses**

```
AscendingComparator comp1 ...
DescendingComparator comp2 ...

Collections.sort(list, comp1); // Sort ascending
Collections.sort(list, comp2); // Sort descending
```

Comment: how to use hash map array list in this comparator

Comment: You mean an `HashMap` of `ArrayList` ?

Comment: am get values from j son put in hash map and then i add the hash map values in array list.

Comment: To sort the `ArrayList`, just use the code above and replace *list* with the name of your `ArrayList`. Of course you have to code at least one Comparator class to have the sort to work.

Comment: To sort a `HashMap` it seems like you have to use [another solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java), which is in fact very similar to the code I gave you.